# Pass org-mode table data into org-mode C++ source code block

Tags: c++, org-mode

How do I properly access org-mode table data in C++?

```
#+tblname: prob-calc
| a | 353.02 |
| b | 398.00 |
| c |  241.0 |
| d |      1 |

#+begin_src C++ :var tbl=prob-calc :includes <stdio.h> :results output
// in other languages, say python, you can just evaluate tbl to 
// see the values (and of course access them in the usual python 
// way. Same for R, Common Lisp. Is it possible with C++? My 
// suspicion is that it can't be done in C++.
// What goes here to do it?
#+end_src
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
#+tblname: prob-calc
| a | 353.02 |
| b | 398.00 |
| c |  241.0 |
| d |      1 |

#+begin_src C++ :var tbl=prob-calc :includes <iostream> <cstdlib> :results output
int row, col;
for (row=0; row < tbl_rows; row++) {
  for (col=0; col < tbl_cols; col++) {
    std::cout << tbl[row][col] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a 353.02 
: b 398.0 
: c 241.0 
: d 1
```

On Linux, the source file is written in `/tmp/babel-<mumble>/C-src-<mumble>.cpp`, and the table declaration in that file looks like this:

```
const char* tbl[4][2] = {
  {"a","353.02"},
  {"b","398.0"},
  {"c","241.0"},
  {"d","1"}
};
const int tbl_rows = 4;
const int tbl_cols = 2;
```